# Windows App Store execute simply cmd command

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps

I need execute simply command in cmd.exe, for example:
ls -l

I care to read the result of executing this command, but I know I didn't Process library. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use so called "brokered components" to achieve this. This worked for Windows 8.1, I'm not 100% sure but think it still works for W10. 
It's a little hacky. The reason is that it requires extra steps to get along with the security restrictions in Windows and therefore you need some additional projects and  stuff
Here's a link to a blogpost on this:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mim/2014/06/24/create-a-winrt-brokered-component-feedback-from-a-real-life-developement/ You will find more details if you search for "brokered components".

You can see it in action in a video I recorded for YouTube some month ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yiZBG6PQmY